# Can't update woocommerce product image with C#

Tags: c#, api, rest, woocommerce

I've been trying to update my product images on Woocommerce using their Rest API, the same way i update other product parameters.
However i haven't succeeded even after checking and double checking the structure of the the put request i am sending.
I have no idea what im doing wrong.

```
public async void Command(Product product)
    {

        List<ProductImage> imageList = new();
        
        string imageName = product.Sku.Replace("/", "_") + ".jpg";
        Console.WriteLine(imageName);

        string image_link = "https://website.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/" + imageName;
        Console.WriteLine(image_link);
        imageList.Add(new ProductImage(product.Sku, image_link));

        Dictionary<string, List<ProductImage>> wpFormat = new();
        wpFormat.Add("image", imageList);

        StringContent content = new(JsonSerializer.Serialize(wpFormat));
        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(wpFormat));

        Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = client.PutAsync(url + product.Id, content);
        product.SetTask(task);
    }
```

My ProductImage object structure is the following:

```
public class ProductImage
{
    public string src { get; private set; }
    public string name { get; private set; }

    public ProductImage(string imageName, string source)
    {
        name = imageName;
        src = source;
    }
}
```

}

the content i send is structured in the following manner:

> {"image":[{"src":"https://website.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/6780312.jpg","name":"6780312"}]}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: First question on stackoverflow so i apologize for any mistakes i'm making.

*Edit showing how the comand function is called

```
private async Task MakeRequest(List<Product> products, ICommand comander)
    {
        string choice;
        foreach (Product product in products) { comander.Command(product); tasks.Add(product.task); }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        foreach (Product product in products)
        {
            if (comander is ImageSetter) { choice = "images"; }
            else { choice = "stock_quantity"; }

            object response = ApiHandler.GetResponseData(product.task, choice);
            Console.WriteLine($"{product.Sku}: {response}");
        }
    }
```

Comand is part of an interface that can either be used to alter stock or what im trying here which is setting an image to a product.

Comment: What is the `product.SetTask(task)`? You need to await the `putAsync()` method.

Comment: @ggeorge it is a function that sets the task to the specific product, i then await all of the responses, as i usually have to do this for 3000+ products and it seemed easier to maintain this way.

Comment: Could you show us how do you call the `Command` method? Or where do you await the task that have stored in product

Comment: @ggeorge ok i will edit the question and add the call.

Comment: Did you try it with eg. Postman to see if api works as expected?

Comment: @ggeorge i don't know what Postman is, but i have checked that the api works, i can alter the stock using similar methods, and this gets me a response from the website however it doesn't set the image, the response comes back with an empty image array, ex: "images": [].
I apologize if i'm being confusing.

Comment: If you use their api it might helps you.
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#update-a-product

Comment: @ggeorge Thank you for indicating Postman, with it also failing and assuming the structure of my request is correct im guessing it has to do with woocommerce itself.

Comment: Hello. I guess that you should update/upload some WordPress Media Image AND THEN, set/update your WooComerce product images including that WordPress Media Image ID.

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues I have done exactly that, if i didn't have media uploaded i wouldn't be able to know if the image attachment process was working properly or not. unfortunately so far haven't made any progress in this regard. Any other advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your ProductImage must have the media ID, position and sourceID.

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues Ok so i have to get those from the Wordpress API first is what you were saying before? i misunderstood then, i will try that since in the docs i didn't find mention of those being required.

Comment: Yes...no documentation available.... And yes...MediaID is required! I guess that its the only one you must privide